# Cannot retrieve xml column using Queryable(PageSize=1) attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, odata

I am trying to retrieve rows from SQL Server via Entity Framework using OData with ASP.NET Web API. I am encountering a problem when one of the columns is an xml type. If I return the whole set using [Queryable] in the following controller there are no problems:

```
public class TradesController : ODataController
{
    private readonly HermesContext _db = new HermesContext();

    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Trade> GetTrades()
    {
        return _db.trades;
    }
}
```

But when I use [Queryable(PageSize = 1)] on my action I get the following error:

```
The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.
```

This is because the sql that the Entity Framework has generated (viewed through profiler) is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[trade_reference] AS [trade_reference], 
[Extent1].[trade_id] AS [trade_id], 
[Extent1].[last_updated] AS [last_updated], 
[Extent1].[client_application_code] AS [client_application_code], 
[Extent1].[trade_markup] AS [trade_markup]
FROM [dbo].[Trade] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[client_application_code] ASC, [Extent1].[last_updated] ASC,     [Extent1].[trade_id] ASC, [Extent1].[trade_markup] ASC, [Extent1].[trade_reference] ASC
```

[trade_markup] is an xml type and its inclusion in the ORDER BY clause is causing the error. If I remove '[Extent1].[trade_markup] ASC', and run the remainder of the sql (manually) it executes fine.

The mapping for trade is:

```
public class tradeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Trade>
{
    public tradeMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.trade_reference);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.trade_id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.trade_reference)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.client_application_code)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Trade");
        this.Property(t => t.trade_id).HasColumnName("trade_id");
        this.Property(t => t.trade_reference).HasColumnName("trade_reference");
        this.Property(t => t.last_updated).HasColumnName("last_updated");
        this.Property(t => t.client_application_code).HasColumnName("client_application_code");
        this.Property(t => t.trade_markup).HasColumnName("trade_markup");
    }
}
```

which uses a basic POCO:

```
public partial class Trade
{
    public int trade_id { get; set; }
    public string trade_reference { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
    public string client_application_code { get; set; }
    public string trade_markup { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to specify when using [Queryable(PageSize = 1)] that I want the xml column to be excluded from the ORDER BY clause? I was hoping to do this somewhere in the mapping but I cannot work out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

Let me explain: when you add a PageResult or use $skip or $top, Web API will automatically add a default ordering for you so that the results are stable. You can turn off the default ordering like this:

```
[Queryable(PageSize = 1, EnsureStableOrdering=false)]
```

You may still want to add some kind of ordering to your IQueryable if the results aren't already ordered by your database.

Comment: Thanks Youssef for the quick response. This solved my issue. I am now getting the first trade back with the link to the next trade as expected. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote as well.